# simple C program isn't working

Tags: c

I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Part B

Write a program that:

defines an array of 10 ints
assigns factorial(x) to array element x, for x in the range 0 through 9, inclusive
copies those array elements into a second array of 10 ints, but in reverse order (i.e., element 0 is factorial(9), element 1 is factorial(8), and so on)
prints out that second array to the terminal*/

int factorial(int n){
    int factorial = 1;
    while(n>1){
        factorial = n*factorial;
    }
    return factorial;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int arr1[10];
    int arr2[10];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d", i);
        arr1[i] = factorial(i);
    }

    for(i = 9; i>=0; i--){
        arr2[i] = arr1[9-i];
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

but when I run it it just sits there. I think it's something to do with the call to factorial, because when I comment that out it works instantly, but with it in, it isn't even getting to the first printf.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whoa function name same as local variable..that's preposterous! Please change that

Comment: You are not decreasing the value of n in factorial function.

Comment: `while(n>1){` but you don't alter `n` in the loop, so you will loop forever.  The output from the first `printf` is probably sitting in a buffer.  Use `fprintf(stderr,"%d ", arr2[i]);` instead - stderr is not buffered.

Comment: Use recursion to calculate factorial, that's an excellent exercise (see Romil's answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while(n > 1){
    factorial = n*factorial;
}
```

you missed `n--`;

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me. It doesn't let you for like 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop:

```
while(n>1){
    factorial = n*factorial;
}
```

Will run forever. There is nothing in that loop that can change `n`, so if the loop is entered then we know `n` will always be greater than `1`. You should decrement `n` within your loop:

```
while(n > 1){
    factorial = n--*factorial;
}
```

If you aren't used to seeing decremenent like that you can also do it on a new line:

```
while(n>1){
    factorial = n*factorial;
    n--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decrement `n` in `factorial` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong implementation of factorial method.

```
int factorial(int n){
 int factorial = 1;
 while(n>1){
     factorial = n*factorial;
     n--;
 }
 return factorial;
}
```

Your code simply didn't do anything with n variable and kept multiplying, without ever decreasing n value. Hope this helps